# null returned from Java fails on comparision in Kotlin tests

Tags: kotlin

Java class

```
class Processor{
  Long getLatestOffset(){
    return null
  }
}
```

Kotlin Test

```
@Test
fun testNull() {
  assertThat(processor.latestOffset).isNull() ---> Fails
  assertThat(processor.latestOffset as Long?).isNull() --->Passes
}
```

Can anyone explain the reason around it? I find the casting totally unnecessary.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find the doc of `assertThat()`? Simple comparision using `==` with `null` gave me `true` for both.

Comment: You are correct, this seems to be library issue. Verified that assert(adapter.latestOffset == null) is passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Long` Java member translated to Kotlin default is `Long!`, which means Kotlin have no idea where it is nullable or not. Therefore Kotlin's null-safety is lost here. Casting to Kotlin nullable type is necessary in order to get a Kotlin `null`, otherwise you will get `IllegalStateException`.

If you add `@Nullable` in the Java class, it will be directly translated to `Long?` in Kotlin.

If you add `@NonNull` in the Java class, it will be translated to `Long` in Kotlin.